# Making a Bootstrap table column fit to content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap, and drawing a table. The rightmost column has a button in it, and I want it to drop down to the minimum size it needs to fit said button.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<table class="table table-responsive">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Payment Method</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bart Foo</td>
                <td>Visa</td>
                <td><a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="/Payments/View/NnrN_8tMB0CkVXt06nkrYg">View</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

This renders like this:

[image: Table Example]

With some firebug highlighting, the column width has come out this wide:

[image: Column Width]

That column scales with the page, while the page is in the larger dynamic width modes. I have some idea how I'd go about fixing this in pure CSS, but most of those approaches will probably cause issues with the low width versions of the site.

How would I make that column drop down to the width of its contents?

*(As ever - Existing bootstrap classes > pure CSS > Javascript)*

Comment: Having posted this, I've just had a thought - if I just right align that column, I guess that's about the same - if the other columns have enough data in them to need the space, they'll claw it back anyway. EDIT: Doh - this doesn't work where I have more than one column I need to drop down to a minimum size.

Comment: Thats true for layout, but tables are absolutely fine for tabular data.

Comment: You should use divs instead of tables. You then could assign percentage values for their widths to match the page width.

Comment: Tables should not be used for *structure*. You can use tables for data that usually goes into tables. Octopoid is not using the table tag for structure, it is being used to display data. It is a correct use of the table tag.

Answer (score 215, accepted):

Make a class that will fit table cell width to the content

```css
.table td.fit, 
.table th.fit {
   white-space: nowrap;
   width: 1%;
}
```

Comment: Gah - I'd put this in a `td` rule then applied it to a `th` - that works perfectly, thanks. :) (Hope you don't mind, I added the th rule into your answer too)

Comment: why not width: 1%;?

Answer (score 54):

Add **w-auto** native bootstrap 4 **class** to the **table** element and your table will fit its content.

[image]

Comment: This one worked for me in Firefox, and it's an actual Boostrap solution.

Comment: This is the best solution

Comment: But OP needs that only the rightest column have auto width, not all columns...

Comment: Works along bootstrap 5. Solution I implemented.

Answer (score 46):

Updates

- Aug 2023: Updated the scss code

## Tested on Bootstrap 4.5 and 5.0

None of the solution works for me. The `td` last column still takes the full width. So here's the solution works.

### CSS

Add `table-fit` to your `table`

```css
table.table-fit {
  width: auto !important;
  table-layout: auto !important;
}
table.table-fit thead th,
table.table-fit tbody td,
table.table-fit tfoot th,
table.table-fit tfoot td {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

### Scss

Here's the one for `scss` uses.

```css
@mixin width {
    width: auto !important;
}
table {
    &.table-fit {
        @include width;
        table-layout: auto !important;
        thead th,
        tbody td,
        tfoot th,
        tfoot td  {
            @include width;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The sass version worked like a charme, just copy, paste & compile. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to CSS, where !important is required to make anything work.

Answer (score 15):

Kind of an old question, but I arrived here looking for this. I wanted the table to be as small as possible, fitting to its contents. The solution was to simply set the table width to an arbitrarily small number (1px for example). I even created a CSS class to handle it:

```css
.table-fit {
  width: 1px;
}
```

And use it like so:

```
<table class="table table-fit">
```

Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cecilmonk/tee204y7/)

Bootstrap 4 example with adjusted CSS

```css
.table-fit {
  width: 1px!important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-VHvPCCyXqtD5DqJeNxl2dtTyhF78xXNXdkwX1CZeRusQfRKp+tA7hAShOK/B/fQ2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<h3>Regular Table</h3>

<table class="table table-bordered">
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h3>Compact Table</h3>

<table class="table table-bordered table-fit">
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Key</td>
    <td>Value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: The question is reffering to only some columns of a table, not to all columns of the table

Comment: Yeah, but needing to find a solution to my problem, I arrived here. I explained this in my answer.

Comment: It's still an inappropriate and incorrect answer to this question.

Comment: I made adjusted Bootstrap 4 snippet of your sample (needed the `!important`)

Answer (score 13):

This solution is not good every time. But i have only two columns and I want second column to take all the remaining space. This worked for me

```
 <tr>
    <td class="text-nowrap">A</td>
    <td class="w-100">B</td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h5>Left</h5>
<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Action</th>        
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Payment Method</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td  style="width:1px; white-space:nowrap;">
                <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="/Payments/View/NnrN_8tMB0CkVXt06nkrYg">View</a>
                <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="/Payments/View/NnrN_8tMB0CkVXt06nkrYg">Edit</a>
                <a role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="/Payments/View/NnrN_8tMB0CkVXt06nkrYg">Delete</a>                
            </td>        
            <td>Bart Foo</td>
            <td>Visa</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h5>Right</h5>

<table class="table table-responsive">
    <tbody>
        <tr>                    
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Payment Method</th>
            <th>Action</th>            
        </tr>
        <tr>

            <td>Bart Foo</td>
            <td>Visa</td>
            <td  style="width:1px; white-space:nowrap;">
                <a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="/Payments/View/NnrN_8tMB0CkVXt06nkrYg">View</a>
                <a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="/Payments/View/NnrN_8tMB0CkVXt06nkrYg">Edit</a>
                <a role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="/Payments/View/NnrN_8tMB0CkVXt06nkrYg">Delete</a>                
            </td>            
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is really the same as the accepted answer except injected as a `style=` attribute - not saying this is not a valid answer but just calling that out for others who visit this.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your table around the div tag like this as it helped me too.

```
<div class="col-md-3">

<table>
</table>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

None of the provided answers worked for me. If anyone stumbles upon this problem, here's a clean solution which also works with Boostrap 4.6.

By using `colgroup`, we can adjust the width of entire columns. So we set width to 1% for the columns we want to fit to content. Just make sure to add the appropriate number of `col` elements for your columns:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <colgroup>
        <col>
        <col>
        <col style="width: 1%;">
      </colgroup>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Payment Method</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Bart Foo</td>
          <td>Visa</td>
          <td><a role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="">View</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div> 
</div>
```

(added a border to the table to better visualize the result)

If you don't like the inline style you can always move it to a CSS class and apply it to the col element.

Answer (score -3):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Payment Method</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bart Foo</td>
        <td>Visa</td>
        <td><a role="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" href="/Payments/View/NnrN_8tMB0CkVXt06nkrYg">View</a></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to this place! When leaving answers please also make sure to not only leave a piece of code. It is also important to explain what the code does, to clear things up.

Comment: If you compare my code with the provided code you will see the difference. My answer is not lonely without explain. So don't dismiss it.

Comment: This fails to address the question - make the rightmost column width as small as the button width.

Comment: You shouldn't expect everyone to compare line-by-line to see what you're proposing as a solution. See [answer].