# How to correctly add a button in a cell of a table?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I added a "delete" button in a cell of my table, my problem is that the height of my cell has changed, I decided to reduce the height of the button but I still have the same problem.

A person has the same problem as me, a solution has been shared -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31184000/making-a-bootstrap-table-column-fit-to-content)

The solution is to reduce the button with `btn-xs`

I have tried but still have the same problem.

```
<td class="text-center">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
</td>
```

The height of the third line with the `delete` button is not the same as the other lines.

[image]

If anyone has a solution to share in Bootstrap 4, I'm interested because I want to avoid CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
  <link
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
</head>
<body>
  <br/><br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th scope="col" colspan="2">Valeur</th>
          <th scope="col" colspan="2">Achat</th>
          <th scope="col" colspan="2">Vente</th>
          <th scope="col" colspan="2">Cours</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th scope="col">Code bourse</th>
          <th scope="col">Libellé</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantité</th>
          <th scope="col">Limite</th>
          <th scope="col">Limite</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantite</th>
          <th scope="col">Dernier</th>
          <th scope="col">Volume</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="text-center">AED</th>
          <td>AEDIFICA SA</td>
          <td class="text-right">210</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,500</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,700</td>
          <td class="text-right">92</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,600</td>
          <td class="text-right">12</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="text-center">ASC</th>
          <td>ASCENCIO</td>
          <td class="text-right">210</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,500</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,700</td>
          <td class="text-right">92</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,600</td>
          <td class="text-right">12</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="text-center">BANI</th>
          <td>BANIMMO</td>
          <td class="text-right">210</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,500</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,700</td>
          <td class="text-right">92</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,600</td>
          <td class="text-right">12</td>
          <td class="text-center">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the padding-y (`py-*`) of the cell, the button, or both.

```
<td class="text-center py-1">
     <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
</td>
```

Delete

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML CSS JS</title>
  <link
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  rel="stylesheet"
/>
</head>
<body>
  <br/><br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
      <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th scope="col" colspan="2">Valeur</th>
          <th scope="col" colspan="2">Achat</th>
          <th scope="col" colspan="2">Vente</th>
          <th scope="col" colspan="2">Cours</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="text-center">
          <th scope="col">Code bourse</th>
          <th scope="col">Libellé</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantité</th>
          <th scope="col">Limite</th>
          <th scope="col">Limite</th>
          <th scope="col">Quantite</th>
          <th scope="col">Dernier</th>
          <th scope="col">Volume</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="text-center">AED</th>
          <td>AEDIFICA SA</td>
          <td class="text-right">210</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,500</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,700</td>
          <td class="text-right">92</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,600</td>
          <td class="text-right">12</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="text-center">ASC</th>
          <td>ASCENCIO</td>
          <td class="text-right">210</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,500</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,700</td>
          <td class="text-right">92</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,600</td>
          <td class="text-right">12</td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <th scope="row" class="text-center">BANI</th>
          <td>BANIMMO</td>
          <td class="text-right">210</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,500</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,700</td>
          <td class="text-right">92</td>
          <td class="text-right">116,600</td>
          <td class="text-right">12</td>
          <td class="text-center py-1">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-xs">Delete</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```